# Rotation should not work after applying QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformation flag

Tags: qt, rotation, qgraphicsview

I have three level of hierarchy of items on a GraphicsView:

1. An ellipse2 whose ItemIgnoresTransformations is OFF (parent GraphicsView)
2. an ellipse3 whose ItemIgnoresTransformations is ON  (parent ellipse2)
3. a text Item whose ItemIgnoresTransformations is OFF (parent ellipse3)

So now I want To rotate textItem only when ellipse3 is rotated not when the whole view is rotated.
It is working fine in case of view rotation But when i rotated ellipse3 then text also rotates though its transformation is OFF Please explain me how it is possible??

```
#include <QApplication>
#include<QGraphicsView>
#include<QGraphicsScene>
#include<QGraphicsTextItem>
#include<QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView graphicsView;//Graphics View

    QGraphicsScene graphicsScene;
    graphicsView.setScene(&graphicsScene);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem ellipse2(QRectF(0,0,4,4));//ellipseItem2
    ellipse2.setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
    graphicsScene.addItem(&ellipse2);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem ellipse3(QRectF(10,0,4,4),&ellipse2);//ellipseitem3

    QGraphicsTextItem textItem("TEXT",&ellipse3);
    textItem.setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
    textItem.setPos(10,0);

    ellipse3.rotate(90);
    graphicsView.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In Qt transformations are passed to the child items from parent.But in my case i have stooped the transformation of the child textItem, but when i call rotate ellipse3 its transformations are passed to the child.